# Pattern Matcher gets ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, junit, pattern-matching, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is the pseudocode of what I'm trying to do:

```
procedure naive(T, P):
result = { }
for s = 0 to n – m
    match = true
    for j = 0 to m – 1
        if T[s+j] ≠ P[j]
            match = false
    if match
        result = result + {s}
```

Here's what I've written:

```
public class naivepatternmatcher {
    public static Integer[] main(char[] T, char[] P) {
        Integer[] results = {};
        int count = 0;
        boolean match;
        for (int s = 0; s <= (T.length - P.length); s++) {
            match = true;
            for (int j = 0; j <= P.length - 1; j++) {
                if (T[s + j] != P[j]) {
                    match = false;
                }
            }
            if (match == true) {
                results[count] = s;
                count++;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

When I try to run my Junit test class I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at "results[count] = s;" in my main and "Integer[] results = naivepatternmatcher.main(Sequence, Pattern1);" in my Junit Test.

```
public class naivepatternmatcherTest {

private static final char[] Sequence = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a',
        'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a',
        'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c' };

@Test
public void test() {
    char[] Pattern1 = new char[] { 'a', 'a', 'b' };
    Integer[] ShouldEqual = new Integer[] { 3, 10, 17, 24 };
    Integer[] results = naivepatternmatcher.main(Sequence, Pattern1);
    assertArrayEquals(ShouldEqual, results);
}
}
```

Can anyone solve this to me and explain what I am missing?

Comment: Or: `Integer[] results = {};` --> `Integer[] results = new Integer[T.length - P.length];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `results` is an empty array with a fixed size of 0 and results[count] = s won't increase the array's size by one and append the value of `s` to it. Better use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for such a dynamically growing results.

Another suggestion is that you add a call to `break` at the end of your inner for loop's if because if `T[s + j] != P[j]` there is no need to further search for the rest of the pattern.

```
if (T[s + j] != P[j]) {
    match = false;
    break
}
```

See the following code for an example of implementation that keeps your returntype of `Integer[]` and only internally uses an `ArrayList`.

```
public static Integer[] main(char[] T, char[] P) {
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean match;
    for (int s = 0; s <= (T.length - P.length); s++) {
        match = true;
        for (int j = 0; j <= P.length - 1; j++) {
            if (T[s + j] != P[j]) {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match == true) {
            results.add(s);
        }
    }
    return results.toArray(new Integer[results.size()]);
}
```

[See it run live](http://ideone.com/t1oOi3)